# How to find a match for this laminate flooring

Tags: flooring, replacement, laminate-floor

A previous owner installed laminate flooring in a couple of rooms, and I'd like to find an exact match to this flooring so I can install in another adjacent area.  There are a couple of spare boards which I have measured and photographed.

- The floor surface is **137mm** (5⅜") wide x **1286mm** (50⅝") long (not including interlocks).  The boards are **12mm** (½") thick.
- On the back is a code **SG 703** and an apparent timestamp **25.11.08 02:23:52**.  Also on the back is embossed ★★★★★ **Superior Water Resistant Quality** ★★★★★.

The best hint I've found so far is the [Glen Doussie series from Inovar](https://inovarfloor.com/my/index.php/browse-product/laminate-flooring/item/glen-doussie).  These appear to come with codes TZ703, FV703, and MF703.

None of the dimensions of these appear to match exactly, but they are pretty close, and the color/finish looks similar.

How/where do I find an exact match for these laminate boards?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no info to back this up, but I think people normally buy wood flooring at a local store.  Maybe carry it in to some local flooring or home stores and see if anyone recognizes it?  Of course its over 12 years old at this point so finding a match might be impossible.

Comment: A flooring supply company probably can help you better if they see a board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it, for two reasons:

1. Many flooring companies change their products regularly. One of my neighbors had flooring put in 18 months ago, and it is already no longer manufactured.
2. You will have a very hard time matching it exactly, even if you find the same model. The boards that are already installed will have weathered in the time since they were installed due to light, temperature, cleaning, etc. If you put a brand new board next to a board that has been a part of the floor for the last X years, you will see that they look different. Getting the colors to match without completely redoing all of it is incredibly difficult.

I spoke to a local professional remodeler about this exact issue a few years ago, and his recommendation for such cases is to find something that is deliberately contrasting instead of trying to get the color as close as possible.